# Detect element that is being scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have some divs on my page set to overflow: scroll, like so:

[image]

How can I detect which element is currently being scrolled or if the scroll is applied to the body? Event.target only returns the element over which the mouse is currently hovering as the scroll is applied, not the actual target.

```js
window.onscroll = function(e){

 console.log(e.target);

}
```

```css
body{
  background: white;
}

div{
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 25px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
</div>

<div>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
</div>

Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: reason you do not bind scroll events to the element? did you try `e.currentTarget`

Comment: @epascarello I think `e.currentTarget` would always be `window`, since it's the element that the listener was attached to.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) in a code snippet here in your question so that we can reproduce your issue and provide a working answer.

Comment: Why not bind the event onscroll to your divs, and not to the window ?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I made a JSFiddle, please take a look at my edit.

Comment: @iguypouf Since this is a responsive design I do not know which elements will be scrollable.

Comment: Please do make make Fiddles or point to your content at 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question is meaningless to those who come across it. Place your code directly into your question, right here as a code snippet (click the `<>` button on the toolbar while you edit the question). Then, the code can execute right here, just like with a fiddle.

Comment: You can listen the onscroll event on an element which will never be scrolled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** I added a function `isScrollable` so that if your scroller divs are not scrollable (eg. big screens or not enough content), they are not considered as a scrollable element.

You can try going through the ancestors of the  target until you find one that is scrollable:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var el = e.target;
  while (el && el !== document && !isScrollable(el)) {
   el = el.parent;
  }
  log('Scrolled element: '+ (el.className || 'document'));
}, true);

function isScrollable(el) {
  return el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth || el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight;
}

function log(x) {
  document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
/* Some CSS for the demo... */.scroller{width:6em;height:6em;float:left;overflow:scroll;border:4px solid #ddd;margin:.5em;position: relative}.inside{content:"";display:block;width:100em;height:100em;background:url(https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/1604/posts/28343/image/WatermelonOrangePatternFinal.png)}.scroller.d .inside{width:100%;height:100%;opacity:.5}.scroller.d::before{position: absolute;z-index:5;content:"Not scrollable (not enough content)";font-size:.8em;}body{color:#fff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}body::after{content:"";display:block;width:100em;height:100em;background:url(https://365psd.com/images/previews/b0c/icon-pattern-backgrounds-53906.jpg)}h2{position:fixed;bottom:.2em;left:0;width:100%;text-align:center}
```

```html
<div class="scroller a"><div class="inside"></div></div>
<div class="scroller b"><div class="inside"></div></div>
<div class="scroller c"><div class="inside"></div></div>
<div class="scroller d"><div class="inside"></div></div>
<h2>Try scrolling</h2>
```

Comment: This saved me a ton of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Change your event binding to bind the `div` elements directly. If the `div` doesn't have any overflow, it won't be scrollable and therefore won't fire the event.

```js
// Find all the scrollable divs and loop through the collection of them
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(function(div){

  // Bind each to a scroll event listener
  div.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
   console.log(this.id);
  });

});
```

```css
body{
  background: white;
}

div{
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 25px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="something">
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
</div>

<div>Not enough here for scroll event</div>

<div id="something else">
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
</div>

Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
Scroll<br>
```